# wordpress hook triggerd by form submit

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, post

I want to create a custom php code in the newest wordpress version, which is triggered when a custom form from a plugin is triggered. My question is, is there a hook which is fired when any form is submitted and when a post request is fired. I would be very thankful if someone can send me a example code with a wordpress hook that is fired when any form is submitted. My goal is to reall post variables from the submitted post form.

Thank you and best regardes,

Tobias

Comment: Why not use the file in the `action` attribute of the form for calculation of the data?

Comment: I doubt that there is any general hook for that. https://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook has a pretty comprehensive list (not sure how up to date though), and I can not spot anything like a "general" form hook, only specific ones for certain types of forms (registration, comments, etc.)